# Prove that the sequnce converges uniformly to $0$ on $R$

Tags: real-analysis

I need some help here.
I should prove that the  sequence:
$$  \frac{1}{x^2+n}$$
converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

At first I thought that if this sequence converges I can say that the limit $n \to \infty$ will be $0$  (is that idea right?)

Also I know that $f_n \to f$ uniformly converge if $ \forall \epsilon > 0 \text{,  } \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n >N \text{,  } \forall x \in E \text{,  } |f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$

So I tried to solve this problem using above mentioned

Let $\epsilon > 0 $,  $\forall n>N$

$$|\frac{1}{x^2+n} - 0|< \epsilon $$
$$|\frac{1}{x^2+n}|< \epsilon $$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2+N} < \epsilon$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$  N > \frac{1}{\epsilon} - x^2 $$
Is there any way to get rid of $x^2$?

Comment: Note that $0 < \frac{1}{x^2+n} \le \frac 1n$.

Comment: Since $x^2\geq 0$, then $n+x^2\geq n$. Use the squeeze theorem now, since $0\leq\frac{1}{n+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\frac{1}{x^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n}\le \varepsilon$$

for all $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.